# How to get directory name list?

Tags: c#, regex, list

In C#,

I want directory names list.
Type is List and I have full pah list(List fullPathList).
fullpathList is like this..

```
[0] C:\temp\image\a.jpg;
[1] C:\temp\image\b.bmp;
[2] c:\temp\bin\my.exe;
[3] c:\temp\document\resume.doc;
[4] c:\temp\document\timetable.xlsx;
```

In this case,
I want it.

```
List<string> dirs;
[0] iamge
[1] bin
[2] document
```

I guess possible if i using Regx.
But, i dont know detailed method.

how can I do for it?
(dont use loop statement)

Comment: _don't use loop statement: typical limitation for homework? My guess would be you have no "real" filesystem to query but have a "examle" list of strings that look like above? Tailored my answer to work on strings on that premise. You might wan't to check in using Linq counts as "loop statement". If so you can rerite it with foreach, for, while, do-while or whatever you are allowed to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this prints what you want...

```
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var files = new string[] {
                @"C:\temp\image\a.jpg",
                @"C:\temp\image\b.bmp",
                @"c:\temp\bin\my.exe",
                @"c:\temp\document\resume.doc",
                @"c:\temp\document\timetable.xlsx",
            };
            var dirNames = files.Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).Name);
            Debug.WriteLine($"dirNames={string.Join(",", dirNames)}");
        }
    }
}
```

The Path.GetDirectoryName() returns the full path and new DirectoryInfo().Name returns just the name of the last part of the path.

If you want the result in a list, use...

```
var dirNames = files.Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).Name).ToList();
```

Comment: var dirNames = files.Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).Name).Distinct().ToList(); // add Distinct()

Comment: thank you.but if it has child directory it doesnt work?

Comment: The code should work regardless of how many child directories are used.  The code should return "image" if the path is "c:\temp\a\b\c\d\e\image\x.jpg" and should return "image" if the path is "c:\image\x.jpg".

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solution Works.
it gets all the directory in the specified drive.
Please go through the reference link [ref link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-get-information-about-files-folders-and-drives)

```
        List<string> dir = new List<string>();
        System.IO.DriveInfo di = new System.IO.DriveInfo(@"D:\");
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo = di.RootDirectory;

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] dirInfos = dirInfo.GetDirectories("*.*");

        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo d in dirInfos)
        {
            dir.Add(d.Name);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a real filesystem [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) is the way to go.

If you do *not* have a real filesystem to query, but have a list of strings that are *like* paths you can use [System.IO.Path - Static methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) to split them up like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // some strings that are like paths
        var dirs = new[] 
        {
            @"C:\temp\image\a.jpg", @"C:\temp\image\b.bmp", @"c:\temp\bin\my.exe", 
            @"c:\temp\document\resume.doc", @"c:\temp\document\timetable.xlsx"
        };

        // this will use a static method to extract only the path-part
        var fullDirs = dirs.Select(d => Path.GetDirectoryName(d)).ToList();

        // this will use the same method but split the result at the default systems
        // path-seperator char and use only the last part, only uses distinct values
        var lastDirsDistinct = dirs.Select(d => Path.GetDirectoryName(d)
                    .Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last()
                ).Distinct().ToList();

        // joins the list with linebreaks and outputs it
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", fullDirs));

        // joins the list with linebreaks and outputs it            
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lastDirsDistinct ));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\image
C:\temp\image
c:\temp\bin
c:\temp\document
c:\temp\document
image
bin
document
```